# get JSON from 404 response from a Http.get()

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to get JSON from a 404 response but I only get the

```
Response {_body: "{myJSON}", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers…}
```

How do I get the `object` itself so I can print it on my HTML using for example `{{error.text}}` as I did on my `http.get()`?

This is my code :

```
getList(): Promise<Response> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'list/')
.toPromise() 
.then(response => { 
  console.log(response.json()); return response.json()})
.catch(this.handleErrorPromise)   
}
//if an error ocurred while doing api calls 
  private handleErrorPromise (error: Response | any) {
  console.error("EEEEE" + error.message || error);
  return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
```

when it joins in `.then` it does good, it returns an object so on my `component` I can use it (I'm using this on my component... let me know if it's good or is there any other approach please)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.ListServiceProvider.getList().then( 
list=> {this.mList= list; console.log(list)}, 
error => {this.errorMessage = error; console.log(error)}); 
}
```

So on my HTML I have a `*ngIf=errorMessage` so it joins on that div, not when the response is OK, but it's not showing what I want that is the JSON... can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you able to log the Response?

Comment: Yes but when it's not 404 it shows an  object in my console, but when it's 404 it returns what I said a Response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the new Angular If else in this case

```
  <ng-template #fetching>
    //you can even check here optional ngIf
    <p *ngIf = "errorMessage">{{errorMessage?.imageURL}</p> // update after comment
  </ng-template>

  <p *ngIf="mList; else fetching;">
  // when Data comes do something here else use the else template
  </p>
```

Comment: But I don't want to show for example "Error no data found" I want to show the result of JSON from 404 error

Comment: It's not returning me an object... just a response

Comment: @Stuart2041 if it is not returning the response that is what i asked are you able to log the response you told yes, when the response is 404 are you handling that situation in code are you returning any object ?

Comment: I see this  on my console Response {_body: "{myJSON}", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers…}

Comment: @Stuart2041 in the component console or service ? and what do you want to display on error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147442/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-stuart2041).

Comment: can you join chat 5 min?